# My Acer laptop will not boot

Tags: windows-7

Acer V5 laptop with Windows 7 installed displays the following error when I turn it on:

> Operating system not found.

The hard drive can be detected in the BIOS. What is wrong with my laptop?

Comment: We need more details. Has it worked before? Have you changed any system settings recently? Installed/uninstalled any programs?

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure the hd is connected properly in the laptop
2. Make sure the hd is in the proper boot sequence in Bios.
3. And remove any external usb thumb drives and/or memory cards. Your
   laptop might be trying to boot up with a connected usb device.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some other things you might want to try to narrow down the issue.

1. Try booting into safe mode. If the laptop boots in safe mode you most likely have a driver issue.
2. If you have an external SATA drive bay try removing the HD and see if it recognizes the HD. 
   If it does see the drive go to the HD manufacturers website and see if they have a scanning tool to determine if the drive has bad sectors.
3. If you have your OS cd's try running Startup repair.

As gronostaj2 stated more information would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**Method One**

(1) [DOWNLOAD BOOT-REPAIR-DISK](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files),

(2) Then burn it on CD or put it on USB key via Unetbootin,

(3) Insert the Boot-Repair-Disk and reboot the PC,

(4) Choose your language,

(5) Connect internet if possible

(6) Click "Recommended repair"

(7) Reboot the pc --> solves the majority of bootsector/GRUB/MBR problems

[image]

Source : http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/

**Alternative**

If you have a ubuntu live boot cd or usb sitting around, or you can arrange one from your friend,

- boot your computer on a Ubuntu live-CD or live-USB.
- choose "Try Ubuntu"
- connect to the Internet
- open a new Terminal, then type:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update`

- Press ENTER.
- Then type:

`sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)`

- Press ENTER

**Using Boot-Repair**

Recommended repair:

1. launch Boot-Repair from either : the Dash (the Ubuntu logo at the top-left of the screen)
   or System->Administration->Boot-Repair menu (Ubuntu 10.04 only)
2. or by typing 'boot-repair' in a terminal. Then click the "Recommended repair" button. When repair is finished, note the URL (paste.ubuntu.com/XXXXX) that appeared on a paper, then reboot and check if you recovered access to your OSs.
3. If the repair did not succeed, indicate the URL to people who help you by email or forum.

Source : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair